# Cache Dependency Off causing exception

Tags: exception, caching, dependencies

I'm getting an exception in my data tier when I try to disable cache dependency in SQL server:

```
System.Exception: TblSettings::Insert::Error occured. --->
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure
  'dbo.AspNet_SqlCacheUpdateChangeIdStoredProcedure'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Enabling cache dependency, everything is fine. Disabling, the above exception gets thrown. How do I turn this off conclusively? I've checked the code and can't seem to find where it is referenced, apart from the web config, of which I've removed the cache block. From what I can see this seems to be caused via SQL server itself. Anyone any ideas of things to check?

The following is console output I'm trying to turn on and off:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>
  aspnet_regsql -S JDAWG\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P password -d DB -dd

Disabling the database for SQL cache dependency.

.

Finished.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>
  aspnet_regsql -S JDAWG\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P password -d DB -ed

Enabling the database for SQL cache dependency.

.

Finished.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. Found it, There's a trigger under each table that appears to be left over. Needs deleted to prevent the referencing.

Comment: Thanks - that worked for me too.
Unfortunately this command did not clean everything up:
aspnet_regsql -S MySqlServer -dd -E -d MyDatabase